# w2ui библиотека. как сделать фильтрацию вывода записей по RecordID?

Tags: json

Всем привет.
Есть код, который рисует таблицу пользователей:

```
$('#users').w2grid({
    name    : 'users',
    //limit     : 50,
    //url     : 'users.php',
    header  : 'List of Respondents',
    url: {
        get: 'respondents/users.php',
        save: 'respondents/users.php',
        remove: 'respondents/users.php'
    },
    show: {
        header        : true,
        toolbar       : true,
        footer        : true,
        toolbarAdd    : true,
        toolbarDelete : true
    },        
    columns: [
        { field: 'resp_first_name', caption: 'First Name', size: '100px', searchable: true, sortable: true },
        { field: 'resp_last_name', caption: 'Last Name', size: '100px', searchable: true, sortable: true },
        { field: 'resp_mobile', caption: 'Mobile phone', size: '150px', searchable: true, sortable: true },
        { field: 'resp_phone', caption: 'Phone', size: '150px', searchable: true, sortable: true },
        { field: 'resp_email', caption: 'Email', size: '150px', searchable: true, sortable: true }            
    ],

    onAdd: function (event) {
        editUser(0);
    },
    onDblClick: function (event) {
        editUser(event.recid);
    }
});
```

Есть также переменная, которая получает внешние данные в виде

```
    Record = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 14
    [7] => 27
)
```

Можно сделать её в JSON, просто так удобнее, это не принципиально.
Вопрос: есть ли возможность настроить фильтрацию записей в w2grid по recid, которые соответствуют переменной Record? Метод с поиском не подходит, поскольку поиск идет только по видимым полям, перечисленным в columns:, а мне надо по recid, которая не отображается как поле, но априори присутствует в строке, возвращаемой с сервера (users.php). Править ответ на запрос в файле сервера users.php не хотелось бы, т.к. это универсальный файл для всех запросов, а проблема фильтрации записи сугубо локальная для данной страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
onClick: function (event) {
            var data = [];
            var respondents = [];
            var wfrecord = this.get(event.recid);//get workflow uid
            //send POST to PHP and get responce            
            function get_respondents(callback){            
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "wfbase/resplist.php",
                data: {"message" : wfrecord['doc_uid']},
                success: function(data){
                  callback(data);//get responce from url:                  
                }
              });           
            }
            //call get_respondents function
            get_respondents(function(data){                
                var stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
                var stringified = stringified.replace(new RegExp("id","g"), "recid");
                var newdata = JSON.parse(stringified);
                /*console.log('----------------');
                console.log(data); // use data here
                console.log(newdata); // use data here
                console.log('----------------');*/                
                w2ui['users'].clear();
                w2ui['users'].add(newdata);
                w2ui['users'].refresh();
            });
        },
```

У меня 2 таблицы, левая и правая, правая зависит от выбора левой. При клике на строке левой таблицы (событие OnClick) происходит ajax передача через POST серверу данных о выбранной строке в файл resplist.php, от него же получаем ответ в виде JSON данных, соответствующих этой строке в переменную 'data', потом данные обрабатываются к виду, понятному w2ui (замена 'id' MySQL на recid), передаются в правую таблицу (users), после её предварительной очистки. Пришлось писать отдельный обработчик запроса resplist.php, т.к. проще оказалось делать каждый раз запрос к MySQL.